# Имплементация кода Laravel в CMS проект

Tags: php, laravel, cms, joomla

Всем привет.

Есть сайт, созданный на CMS (WordPress или Joomla, точно позже узнаю, если необходимо), с подключенными разаными библиотеками.

Необходимо имплементировать контактную форму с БД и отправкой писем по электронной почте. Помимо этого требуется разработать интерфейс для бэкенд управления БД (другими словами - админская панель).

Всё это выполнять хочу с помошью `laravel`.

Возникает вопрос:

какие проблемы могут возникнуть позже при подключении этого всего, написанного на laravel, к CMS сайту?
Проблема в том, что доступа к сайту я не имею, поэтому буду всё делать на чистом листе. Но потом придётся как-то это всё пришивать к сайту.

Я не сильно опытный в этих архитектурах и CMS-ах. Потому буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Забудь про лаварель при работе с CMS написанных не на ней и делегируй задачу специалистам по движку.

Comment: Вот блин((   А если в любом случае мне придётся это делать (т.к. я не выбираю ТЗ), но я могу только на laravel или на чистом PHP с PDO, как быть? Узнал: сайт на Joomla выполнен.

Comment: Еще раз - делегируй тому кто знает Джумлу.